# FM signal strength of Android

Tags: android, fm-radio

I want to know the FM Radio signal strength in Android. For this I have to interact with hardware or not? Or is there any API which can directly give me the value of signal strength?

Comment: I think FM in android is available from Froyo version. I am not sure whether any APIs have been exposed.

Answer (score 0):

FM radio is available in some phones. Anyways you must have an FM tuner (radio) built-in.

> For this I have to interact with
>   hardware or not?

Yes, of course you will have to as it has not been brought into the stack.

> is there any API which can directly give me the value of signal strength?

I think, NO.

Maybe you will have to write your own jni, and java source and add it to the stack, if you need one.

Comment: "Very few phones do"? My HTC Desire has an FM radio, and so did my previous SE W760i, and my previous phone before that, AND the phone before that. But my experience may be atypical.

Comment: FM Tuner is already in my phone because FM Radio is working fine