# Access signal strength of Android Phone FM receiver?

Tags: android

I want to develop an Android Phone project where I can find the signal strength of any particular FM Station using the on-board FM receiver.

In particular I am interested in the *Samsung I9000 Galaxy S*.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215117/fm-signal-strength-of-android look at the similar issue

Comment: This is going to be vendor specific and maybe even handset specific. You should name the handsets you are targeting.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i am using Samsung I9000 Galaxy S

Comment: i found some files https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/external/gigabyte/froyo-gb-dsds-7227/plain/frameworks/base/core/java/android/hardware/fmradio/ but cant understand how to use it please CAN ANYONE HELP me

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There is no official API for FM radio in Android, till date.

All devices won't have an FM Radio, and devices with FM have proprietary manufacturer-specific API to work with FM radio.

For more info, refer [this post](https://github.com/mikereidis/androidfm/wiki/Creating-an-Android-FM-app)